# What does number of shapes does not match the number of table records mean when trying to repair a data source?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data, error

I'm trying to repair a data source on arc from a .shp file. Every time I match it with the correct .shp file it display an error message stating "Number of shapes does not match the number of record tables". It also will not let me add the desired .shp file to the map either. Is there a way to repair this connection

Answer (score 2):

There is an [Esri technical article](http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/17791) on this subject. This condition is often (unknowingly) created when someone opens a shapefile .dbf file in Excel and makes alterations.  Essentially, the article recommends using a [Shapefile Repair Tool](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=13733).  Keep in mind that this solution will alter the shapefile, so create a backup.

Comment: And if the dBase file order has been compromised, its quite possible that the dataset isn't recoverable (without manual review of all features).

Comment: It doesn't look like that utility is stored at the ESRI code sharing page anymore, I have looked for both the Shapefile Repair Tool and Shapefile Repairer Tools recommended by the ESRI help page but come up with nothing.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED PROBLEM

There is a really simply solution to this problem. It works.

This problem usually occurs when your workstation suddenly shutdowns and you you were not able to save the shapefile. Upon loading the shapefile again on Arc, you will get this error message, "Number of shapes does not match the number of record tables".

There is a simple solution to this,

add the erroneous shapefile to QGIS, QGIS will load that shapefile without any error,
then export that shapefile using QGIS to create a new vector layer.

Load that newly created vector layer or shapefile to Arc and it should would work.

Unlike those shapefile repair tools, this method will keep your attributes intact. It will only delete the last record to match the number of table records